# Work MDM and family sharing

Tags: macos, family-sharing, mdm

Using personal apple id on work mac. Thinking of enabling family sharing. Will doing so give the MDM used by the employer to gain access to the family apple accounts?

Comment: What does gain access mean to you? Will they know the name of the account and the apps you choose to install? Absolutely. Anything else you consider access? Also, how do you think family sharing works or why that would change MDM and macOS settings?

Answer (score 1):

Except error the MDM is only used to push config or app installations (this is how I use it). He can't have access to your password and personnal information. But it can report information from the accounts you are connected to, the apps you have installed and other information. Personally, we don't do this because there's no interest to be spying on our employees. With the MDM we simply update the Apps and configure the macs at a distance for new users, integration of the mac in the LDAP domain, addition/update of NAS url and anything else like that.

Family sharing is only a particular "option" to share content purchased with your account for me. Now if you want to share Apps installed on the mac, it won't work. The best thing is to explain in more detail what you want to do.